# Split Binary number into Digits

Tags: c++, bit

In case of normal integer, we use `%10` for the remainder, and `/10` to reduce the digit by one digit.

For a Binary Digit, I could use `%2` to get the remainder, but how do I remove digits from the Binary number?

If there's a number `0000`, when I perform `/10`, I need `000` and not `0`.

```
 while (bin > 0) {
    int rem = bin % 2;
    // action_block;
    // How do I divide ?
  }
```

Clearing the confusion, this is for a problem of a competitive coding site. The stdin will be an integer, which has a binary data. Example: 1100001. I want its bits in an array. arr[0] = 1, arr[1] = 1, arr[2] = 0, arr[3]=0 and so on..

Comment: What is a _binary number_ actually? Numbers are numbers, number representation systems are number representation systems.

Comment: May be you need << & >> operators ?

Comment: You can use left shift operator.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. :(

Comment: how would a "binary number" be having a floating point?

Comment: You are using `%2` instead of `%10`... Why not use `/2` instead of `/10` ?

Comment: @Shravan40 How exactly? I've not tried using those.

Comment: @AnirudhMurali What exactly *is* the difference between `0000` and `000`?

Comment: @Nelxiost When I perform, say 00101 / 2, I get the output as 32. The output I want is 0010.

Comment: @Rakete1111 I know it doesn't make any difference. It's for a problem, and I need to separate the bits and store in an array. Any other way to do so?

Comment: Why not just convert the number to a string in binary format?  `std::bitset` makes that convenient.

Comment: @AnirudhMurali _"When I perform, say 00101 / 2 ..."_ You are aware that `00101` forms an octal literal, not a binary one?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Sorry for my ignorance, isn't `00101` a binary representation of decimal 5?

Comment: @AnirudhMurali Nope. A leading zero in a literal indicates _octal_ reprsentation, not binary.

Comment: @AnirudhMurali `00101` as a literal in the code is the octal form of 65. As far as I know, there is no standard syntax for binary literals, although `0b101` is probably supported by your compiler.

Comment: @Nelxiost Actually that was added in C++14 :) [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal)

Comment: @NathanOliver Oh that's what I was looking for, thanks !

Comment: There is no number such as  `0000`. Only `0`. You are not explaining your concern the way you should.

Comment: Sorry guys for the confusion, edited the question, Hope it's clear now.

Comment: @AnirudhMurali Nothing clarified at all.

Comment: @AnirudhMurali To shortcut that noise and waste of time overall, could you please provide a [MCVE], that clearly demonstrates your problem right now please!

Answer (score 2):

Right shift `(>>)` operator is used to shift the bits to right by position specified in the expression.

**For example** :

```
unsigned int num1 = 12; // 12 = 1100 
int num2 = 0;           
num2 = num1 >> 1; // 6 = 0110
int num3 = 0;
num3 = num1 >> 2; // 3 = 0011
```

Now, try achieving your goal using this.

**Edit :**

As problem described by OP in comment section of this answer.

```
std::string inp;
std:: cin >> inp.
for (int i = 0; i < inp.length(); i++) {
    std::stoi(inp[i]); // This will be 0,1.
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid the OP's suffering from more fundamental misunderstandings currently.

Comment: I do not think this is what the OP needs.  It looks like they are trying to split a number but instead of `123` into `1`, `2`, `3` they want `1`, `1`, `1`, `1`, `0`, `1`, `1`.

Comment: This is for a problem in CodeChef, the stdin will be an integer, which has a binary data. Example: 1100001. I want it as bits in an array. arr[0] = 1, arr[1] = 1, arr[2] = 0.. and so on. Hope I'm clear now. Sorry again.

Comment: @AnirudhMurali : Why don't you take input as `std::string` and access element using it's index. You can convert string into integer using `std::stoi(str)`.

Comment: @NathanOliver : I have edited my aswer, as OP described his problem in comment section.

Comment: @AnirudhMurali Please refrain asking questions about online code judge engines here. It's very  unlikely that anyone could tell you where you failed from their test cases, as these aren't disclosed usually. Even if what you tested was running at your local environment, you may have missed to test some edge cases which are applied in the online challenge. Be creative and try to find them. Additionally there's probably no value for such questions in the long term, other than cheating the online contest, and nothing is learned.

Comment: @AnirudhMurali _"Isn't StackOverflow meant to clarify queries?"_ Nope, clarify your question substantially first.

Answer (score 2):

Quite logically, use /2. It's the same with any base.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an array then this is what you are looking for :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string input="0101011010";
  int arr[10];
  for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
  {
    arr[i]=input[i]-'0'; 
  }
  for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
  {
    cout << arr[i] << endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: What you've done is with what I'm trying to achieve. But the same with integer datatype as input. And by the way, what does `-'0'` mean?

Comment: @AnirudhMurali _"what does -`'0'` mean?"_ `char`s are numbers coming from an encoding table,If you want the plain digits, you can calculate them like that.